# How to get ES6 class constructor from class name?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reflection

Given the following code:

```
class MyClass {}
```

Is there a way to get the `MyClass` constructor from the string, `MyClass`?  I'm looking for something analogous to .NET's [Assembly.GetType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettype?view=netframework-4.8).

**Use case:**

A user of a product authors their own classes via some sort of extensibility; and these classes should be able to be loaded from the global scope by the product when the product is given the name of a given class.

I understand that in most cases this would likely be a terrible design pattern lacking encapsulation, but nonetheless I am curious if this type of reflection is possible in any ECMAScript version.  The way I work around this is to have each class "register" itself using a helper function (or class decorator!) from the main product.

**P.S.**

I notice that while function declarations alter the global scope, class definitions do not:

```js
function hithere() {}
globalThis["hithere"] // hithere(){}
```

```js
class hithere {}
globalThis["hithere"] // undefined
```

Comment: Not necessarily because in JS a class definition is just another variable storing some value. So you could as well write `const Foo = class Bar {}`. Guess what the "name" would be now.

Comment: if you were to do `window.hithere= class hithere {}` you could access it with `globalThis` like in the first example

Comment: Not without parsing the code yourself to find `class` definitions or requiring the code to explicitly register or export the desired classes.  Personally, I like modules so I'd suggest you change the format to a module format and require the code writer to export the classes in some agreed-upon export format.  The module format would also put everything in a private scope and prevent name clashes.